# Unable to Decrypt SD Card after reboot my Samsung s7 Edge?

Tags: samsung, sd-card, data-recovery, encryption, reboot

I moved my important files in Encrypted SD card from my Phone & removed SD card for reboot the phone. After complete the reboot i am unable to find my files in encrypted SD card. When i put my SD card in same mobile which i use for encrypt SD card so it says 
**" This SD card can't be decrypted because it was encrypted in other device. SD cards can only be decypted on the device used to encrypt them. Decrypt the SD card on the device used to encrypt it, then reinsert in this device, and try again."**
I have too much important data if anyone can help me to come out from this problem then kindly let me know.

Thanks.